# Commenting a part of a line with ruby

Tags: ruby, comments

In ruby, you can comment the end of a line like this :

```
puts "This is a line" # Comment for end of line
```

Or multiple lines like this :

```
=begin
Multi
lines
comment
=end
```

How come I can't find any info about a syntax that would only comment a part of a line, for example, in C :

```
if (my_condition()/* || true */)
```

Does it exist in ruby ? If not, why ?

Comment: [It doesn't exist](http://web.njit.edu/all_topics/Prog_Lang_Docs/html/ruby/syntax.html#comment). I don't know why.

Comment: `if (my_condition()/* || true */)` is a bad habit to get into. It creates maintenance issues because it is difficult to see the commented code. Ruby, being a younger language, has a lot of syntax choices based on hind-sight, and doesn't allow comments like that. Be thankful, because in the long run it's a blessing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How come I can't find any ...?

Because there isn't any. If you wanted to do it, perhaps you can do this:

```
some_code.tap{%q{some comments blah blah blah}}.some_more_code_to_continue
```

and you can read `.tap{%q{...}}` as what `/*...*/` would mean in C although it doesn't look so good. In some languages, people do manage to craft inline comments using the existing syntax; for e.g, in TeX, `\if\false...\fi` is often used.

Comment: Really weird cheating with `.tap{%q{…}}` :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is no exact passibility you are looking for, but you can easily fake it with `\n` and `\`:

```
# Inserted `\ #`   ⇓⇓⇓ and CR ⇓⇓⇓  
if (my_condition() \ # || true 
)
```

Comment: The continuation ``\`` isn't necessary. Ruby will automatically grab the closing parenthesis from the next line, and will ignore the commented `|| true`.

Comment: @theTinMan I supposed this is not the only case and someone will try to apply the technique not inside parentheses.